# HMAC SHA1 in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, hmacsha1

I have been tasked to integrate a Classic ASP website with the SageOne API. As part of their authentication you are required to provide a HMAC-SHA1 signature. I've found how to do this with SHA256 here: [hash_hmac in using pure classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126243/hash-hmac-in-using-pure-classic-asp), which worked in that it produced the hash, but was not valid for the API. I've found similar code for SHA1 here: https://precompiled.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/hmac-sha1-encryptie-onder-classic-asp/ but unfortunately the link to the required wsc file is no longer valid. I've not been able to find it elsewhere. Has anyone come across this file elsewhere? Or could anyone point me towards an alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sha1.wsc can be found at https://github.com/chakphanu/labs/blob/master/classic-asp-s3/sha1.wsc

I will not include it here as I don't want to examine the license requirements.